# How to register generic interface with a non generic class

Tags: c#, console-application, unity-container

EDIT :
My original question was polluted with unecessary details.

Here's a simpler way of asking it.

I have this class :

```
public class ComplexDisplayableFinder3 : IDisplayableFinder<ComplexDisplayableDto>
```

And this one

```
public class ComplexDisplayableFinder2 : IDisplayableFinder<ComplexDisplayableDto>
```

And that one

```
public class ComplexDisplayableFinder1 : IDisplayableFinder<ComplexDisplayableDto>
```

The IDisplayableFinder interface is Generic. Here's it's code :

```
    public interface IDisplayableFinder<T>
        where T : IDisplayableDto
    {
        Task<List<T>> Find();
    }
```

How do I register these classes with Unity's DI Container?

I have tried resolving these 3 classes calling this function :

```
        static IUnityContainer CreateContainerAndRegisterClasses()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IDisplayableFinder<>), typeof(ComplexDisplayableFinder1), "1");
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IDisplayableFinder<>), typeof(ComplexDisplayableFinder2), "2");
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IDisplayableFinder<>), typeof(ComplexDisplayableFinder3), "3");
            
            return container;
        }
```

This is the closest I've been to solving this. However, I'm currently getting an exception at runtime saying : No public constructor is available for type `IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto>`.

Comment: Do keep in mind that even though an instance of `ComplexDisplayableDto` can be assigned to a variable of type `IDisplayableDto` that it does not mean an instance of `IDisplayableFinder<ComplexDisplayableDto>` can be assigned to a variable of type `IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto>`. It cannot.

Comment: yeah I think I'm beginning to see what's wrong with this code. I was hoping for the find function to allow me to implement in a way that would allow me to return any type that I want so long as it implemented IDisplayableDto. However, I'm starting to realize that this specific implementation would restrict me to always treat the results of the find function as an IDisplayableDto instead of its actual type specified in T.

in other words, I wanted Find() to return an ComplexDisplayableDto.

Comment: The way I like to think of it is if I have a bowl of apples and I could cast it to a bowl of fruit then I could add a banana to a bowl that only is allowed apples. That's no good.

Comment: Yeah, the way i hate to think about it is : I've been on this for a couple days now, and it's only now starting to fall appart... lol

Comment: I'm still curious though if there's a proper way of registering a generic type with a non generic class. For example, can I not register an List<T> with MyListOfStrings?

Comment: Sure you can. So long as you have `class MyListOfStrings : List<string> { }` then `container.RegisterType(typeof(List<string>), typeof(MyListOfStrings), "1");` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question directly you want cast a `IDisplayableFinder<ComplexDisplayableDto>` to `IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto >`. For this to work you would have to  make your interface [covariant or contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

i.e.

```
IDisplayableFinder<in T>
```

or

```
IDisplayableFinder<out T>
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to tell Unity to register the type "IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto>"  in a way that will make the container understand that I want the classes ComplexDisplayableFinder1, 2, 3 when a class needs to be injected a list of IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto>. The code you're refering to is just what I have at the moment but it's not really what I want as a final result.

Comment: To clarify, the class ComplexDisplayableFinder1 implements the generic interface IDisplayableFinder<T> like this : 
ComplexDisplayableFinder1 : IDisplayableFinder<ComplexDisplayableDto>.

Comment: So you want to do `container.RegisterType<IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto>, ComplexDisplayableFinder1>()` and `container.ResolveAll<IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto>>`, right?

Comment: Yup pretty much.

Comment: However I get an error at compile time when I try that. :(

Comment: Basically says there's no implicit conversion for IDisplayableFinder<IDisplayableDto> to ComplexDisplayableFinder1.

Comment: That is because you must make the interface co/contravariant, otherwise conversion is not possible. Read the article.

Comment: so you're saying, after I make the interface co/contravariant, this line of register should work?

Comment: yes, but be warned that not all interfaces can be made variant. There are a fair amount of good articles on the subject, and it is far to much to go into details about it here.

Comment: Would there be any other way of registering a Generic type with a non generic class? I've messed with the concept of co/contravariance and I'm not really convinced with the results. I'm already having some issues in certain places in the code where I'd like my functions to return the type T provided in the interface and I can't if it doesn't simply remain variant.

Comment: If you cannot make the interface variant then conversion will not work. I would suggest creating a non generic `IDisplayableFinder` that only accepts/returns IDisplayableDto. If you cannot it is an issue with your type model and you will need to rethink how you are designing your application.